# Выделение композиции остается, если удалить её до завершения | IOS | JS

Tags: javascript, ios

Если во время активной композиции в contenteditable очистить содержимое, то получается вот такой артефакт. Словно selection остается, хотя должен удаляться. (Только на IOS) Почему так происходит и как это убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]